# !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file rdavid): Font rdavid at 720 not found

Tags: lyx

Getting this error while trying to compile my lyx doc, using lyx 2.3.2 on arch linux.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See also https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample